# How to Display GIF Image on iPhone UIIMageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i have found some ways but they are actually reading frames and applying transition which reduces the quality of animation..
is there any way to display GIF on iPHone application as it is..?
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Must you use GIF? Can you use a sequence of PNG instead?

Comment: You're wanting to display an animated GIF?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Animated GIF won't animate, but if you have a GIF, save each animation as a separate GIF and then setup animationImages array with all those GIFs you just saved:

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.gif"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

use a web view.

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "animated", ofType: "gif") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        webview.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

this will render your image and animate it as expected.