# How to show gif into UIImageView in Swift?

Tags: animation, swift, gif, ios8

I want use a gif in UIImageView, but I can't.
My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"gif"];
    UIImage *testImage = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    self.dataImageView.animationImages = testImage.images;
    self.dataImageView.animationDuration = testImage.duration;
    self.dataImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    self.dataImageView.image = testImage.images.lastObject;
    [self.dataImageView startAnimating];
}
```

Swift:

```
var url : NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MAES", withExtension: "gif")
```

In objective C I had animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData but in swift I don't know how call this or if not exists..

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/swift-uiimageview-animate-gif-from-url/27922518#27922518

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you're using https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif for `+UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:` and the source code is in Objective-C.

You'll need to first import your Objective-C headers into Swift. **[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)** explains how to do this:

> To import a set of Objective-C files in the same framework target as your Swift code,
>   you’ll need to import those files into the Objective-C umbrella header for the
>   framework.
>
> **To import Objective-C code into Swift from the same framework**
>
> 1. Under Build Settings, in Packaging, make sure the Defines Module setting for that framework target is set to Yes.
> 2. In your umbrella header file, import every Objective-C header you want to expose to Swift. For example:
>
>    `#import "UIImage+animatedGIF.h"`

You can then setup your `testImage` as follows:

```
var testImage = UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData(
    NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url))
self.dataImageView.animationImages = testImage.images
self.dataImageView.animationDuration = testImage.duration
self.dataImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
self.dataImageView.image = testImage.images.lastObject
self.dataImageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! It's ok. But I have other question, there are other form to show a gif directly without IImage+animatedGIF?

Comment: UIImage doesn't support _animated_ GIFs, but you can use still GIF images just like any other image (`UIImage(named: "image.gif")`). However, if you can split your animated GIF into separate still image GIFs, you're able to load them to UIImage animation like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2578648/2155985