# How to add GIF animations or .gif files to CALayer while composing AVPlayerVideo using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer, animated-gif

I am able to set `UIImage` type as contents to `CALayer` reference by using

```
[overlayLayer setContents:(id)[posterImage CGImage]]
```

and then able to add some basic animation to the layer like rotation and opacity.

**But my requirement is to add Gif Image View with animation to parentLayer CALayer?**

I used https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage to play gif files.

**But i am struck while setting this GiF image view as contents of CALayer.**

I if try to add sublayer of this Gif Image View like

```
[parentLayer addSublayer:gifImageView.layer];
```

i am able to set layer but App crashes at `[self.layer setNeedsDisplay];` of `FLAnimated` View class

The ideas which you share might help me.
Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/swift-uiimageview-animate-gif-from-url/27922518#27922518

Comment: Can you get solution ? I Have same issue...

Comment: @Dipen in my issue i am only able to convert a UIImage to CGImage and then set as contents to the CALayer.But i am unable to add layer with animated GIF'S as Composition is  successful but app crashes at these addition of sublayer's.Even i am in search of right solution once i found will provide you.If you are able to fix this issue please let me know here it may help me.

Comment: Okay sure, In my issue I am able to Set GIF But unfortunately it is not animating..

Comment: @Dipen yeah it wont animate it will just display image itself even i too facing this.

Comment: @SivasagarPalakurthy Got the solution ? me still working on this.

Comment: @Dipen,No! CALayer contents accept only CGImage type. Did you try by adding layer of your ImageView as sublayer to the parent layer and then compose it may work for you.

Comment: Yes I try but no success

Comment: May this work for you ..?

Comment: Have you got the solution? I also need to add GIF to a video composition? Please share. :-)