# Animate Gif in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I've been trying to animate a GIF in Swift but it just doesn't work. I think I found a way but there's an error, please help.

Here's the code:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // (Here is the error it states "Cannot assign a value of type '[UIImage?]' to a value of type '[UIImage]?'")
    imageView.animationImages = [

        UIImage(named: "logo1.jpg"),
        UIImage(named: "logo2.jpeg"),
        UIImage(named: "logo3.png")
    ]

    imageView.animationDuration = 3
    imageView.startAnimating()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may run gif files directly, follow the links below;

https://github.com/kaishin/gifu

[How to load GIF image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/swift-uiimageview-animate-gif-from-url)

As far as the issue in you code is, as already 'Leo Dabus' pointed out, is you are not un-wrapping the UIImage instances. Try same code with the following modifications.

```
imageView.animationImages = [

        UIImage(named: "logo1.jpg")!, //File Extension would not be required if .png
        UIImage(named: "logo2.jpeg")!,  //File Extension would not be required if .png
        UIImage(named: "logo3.png")!
    ]

    imageView.animationDuration = 3
    imageView.startAnimating()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to unwrap the optional UIImage returned by UIImage(named:) method. Try like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        imageView.animationImages = [
            UIImage(named: "logo1")!,
            UIImage(named: "logo2")!,
            UIImage(named: "logo3")!]

        imageView.animationDuration = 3
        imageView.startAnimating()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work because the problem is the imageView.animationImages

Comment: Can you elaborate on that reason?

Comment: Is There A Way to make multiple images a gift in swift

Comment: You better double check your code and also if you have properly added the images listed there to your project Images.xcassets

Answer (score 0):

I have created one example for you.

Here is code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        imageView.animationImages = [
            UIImage(named: "1")!,
            UIImage(named: "2")!,
            UIImage(named: "3")!,
            UIImage(named: "4")!,
            UIImage(named: "5")!,
            UIImage(named: "6")!,
            UIImage(named: "7")!,
            UIImage(named: "8")!,
            UIImage(named: "9")!,
            UIImage(named: "10")!,
            UIImage(named: "11")!,
            UIImage(named: "12")!

        ]

        imageView.animationDuration = 3
        imageView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

You can see Result [HERE](https://gyazo.com/2f869e78cd1b34f47d78fd55b0f77caa).

And [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=98743689808200589280) is sample project.