# How can I get Giphy's gifs with using Swift Giphy Client?

Tags: ios, swift, giphy, giphy-api

I found some framework which namely [Giphy Client](https://github.com/rylio/Giphy.swift), to use the Giphy's gifs easily. But there is no tutorial on how to use it. Sorry for this rookie question. Can someone explain me to how can I search the gifs and get them with using this client?

Here is the gif search function :

```
func test(){
    let gif1 = Giphy(apiKey: "dc6zaTOxFJmzC")

    gif1.search("lol", limit: nil, offset: nil, rating: nil) { (gifs, pagination, err) in


    }
}
```

I really don't know what's in the `gifs` value and I'm struggling because of that. There is a lot of subclass like url, id or rankings, but I can't figured it out.

Comment: see, How to load GIF in swift : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift/27922518#27922518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information is available on the GitHub page you linked in your question. To find more about the `gifs` variable, you can use Xcode's Utilities menu (the right side bar) to see documentation when you click on a variable or function.

Alternatively, you can jump to the definition of a variable by holding command and clicking it. The information about the `Gif` object is [available here on GitHub](https://github.com/rylio/Giphy.swift/blob/master/Giphy/Giphy.swift#L44) as well.

It looks like the `gifs` variable is an optional array of `Gif` objects (its type is `[Gif]?`).

The `Gif` object has some useful properties like `id`, `rating`, and `giphyURL` (a `URL` pointing to the actual gif image).

Since you most likely want to get the images themselves, you can make network requests to get the actual image data. This has already been covered extensively on Stack Overflow. Here is an answer to get you started with getting image data from a url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/6658553

Comment: thanks! I'll check everything you sent to me. But I have a question. The last link includes for the images, but I want to use gif. So if I change the type as a gif, do you thing that's gonna work?

Comment: Here's a Stack Overflow answer about downloading gifs specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27922518/6658553

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted so others in the future can benefit as well.

Comment: I checked the last link and the framework for gifs is old and not working for swift 3.

Comment: I would probably post a comment on the answer to see if there's an updated version, or post a new question about it.