# Why extension to UIImage is not working?

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift-extensions

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/08/load-gif-image-in-swift_22.html) to display GIF image on `UIImage`. I have write the extension `UIImage+GIF.swift` which basically like this:

```
extension UIImage {

    public class func gifImage(named: String) -> UIImage {
        ...
    }
}
```

along with bunch other functions.

But when I tried to do this:

```
myImageView.image = UIImage.gifImage(named: "loading.gif");
```

Xcode complains `type UIImage has no member "gifImage"`. Why? Any how can I fix this? Thanks.

EDIT:

I have also tried to make it a static function like this, but it still doesn't work:

```
extension UIImage {

    static func gifImage(named: String) -> UIImage {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift)

Comment: @NiravHathi thanks. I actually found the link in my question through this same QA. which led to the original issue here where I can't access static functions on this particular extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit    
extension UIImage {
        func gifImage(named: String) -> UIImage {
            //Add your logic here
        }
    }
```

This should work.

Comment: How if I want to add a "static" function? Function which I can call from `UIImage` class directly without instantiating it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your extenssion public

```
public extension UIImage {

public func gifImage(named: String) -> UIImage {
    ...
}
}
```

use extenssion like this

```
yourImageView.gifImage(named: "your image name")
```

Comment: I have added the `public` keyword to the `extension` but it still doesn't work...

Comment: don't make it class function i have edited the answer pls check.

Comment: hmm ok let me try it. I need to make modification to the functions though.