# Adding a gif to a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gif

I'm looking to use an animated GIF in my project. Ideally I don't want to use a third party app/API/plugin. I mean if a plugin exists there must surely be a way to program it natively?

All the examples I have looked at involve the aforementioned third party solutions.

Comment: Perhaps this answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922518/6635563

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked with many popular 3rd party gif players and I can tell you that you can probably copy/follow the implementation of a 3rd party library and use it on your own but the thing is, gif playing is a resource hog thing. A well maintained library would definitely be the way to go if you want performance and better resource management.

My suggestion would be [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I've resigned myself to having to explore this 3rd party players, I'll give it a look. Thanks,