# Local gif didn't show when I updated Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I updated Kingfisher from 4.10 to 5.7,however,the gif didn't show on imageView with the same code.

Here is my code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "loading", ofType: "gif")!
let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
```

It's work well with Kingfiser 4.10.

Comment: Not sure why you're using Kigfisher to show local files?

Comment: Try to search for a solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kingfisher library has [local image provider](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#image-from-local-file) that must be used to load local image.

So your code should be changed to this:

```swift
let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "loading", withExtension: "gif")!
let resource = LocalFileImageDataProvider(fileURL: path)
imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
```