# Gif image (from url) is not loading in uiimage view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I am using this solution : [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919620/how-to-load-gif-image-in-swift). Where i am loading the gif from the url. My code look like below :

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var imageList: [String] = ["http://www.gifbin.com/bin/4802swswsw04.gif", "http://www.gifbin.com/bin/4802swswsw04.gif"]
let imageURL = UIImage.gifImageWithURL(imageList[0])
imageView.image = UIImageView(image: imageURL)
```

And i am using this [This link](https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/GIF-Swift/blob/master/GIF-Swift/iOSDevCenters%2BGIF.swift) for gif support as mentioned in that SO. But i am getting error `Cannot assign value of type 'UIImageView' to type 'UIImage?`. Yes i understood. But how can i fix this and i tried to fix with UIImage but image gif was not showing.

Any solution would be helpful.

I tried even :

```
imageView.image = UIImage.gifImageWithURL(imageList[currentnImageIndex])
```

But image was not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the error: `Cannot assign value of type 'UIImageView' to type 'UIImage?`

You're creating an ImageView and then setting it to the .image, so you probably just need to change:

`gifImageView.image = UIImageView(image: imageURL)`

to

`gifImageView = UIImageView(image: imageURL)`

Comment: I have already tried this. My screen is blank..no image is loaded in to my screen

Comment: @turky I just took a look at that library, and its not worth using.   Like everyone said in that SO post, its full of memory leaks.

Comment: Any other alternative  solutions to show gif image ?