# Add a loading gif when application launches with swift

Tags: swift

I would like to ask, how to add a loading gif at the center of the launch image when I launch my app? If not, then what is the closest thing I can do to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is I would drag and drop the .Gif file into your project and then set the .Gif file programmatically as the image of a UIImage in the background. Take a look at this question! [How to show gif into UIImageView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24485308/4988461)

Comment: Can you do that to launch image too? Cause my question is asking towards launch image(the splash screen)

Comment: Yes you can add it to your launch image!:)

Comment: Sorry this is my first time messing with launch image(I'm still a newbie), but  where do I put the codes to manipulate my launchimage? AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?