# Unable to show a *.gif file in a UIImageView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gif

I have a *.gif file that I want to show in a `UIImageView`. I have tried the library [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage), code below. Result is just a static image.

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var img_popup: FLAnimatedImageView!

    var img_popupraw: FLAnimatedImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: NSData(contentsOfFile: "ShitTalk_LoadingAnimation.gif"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        img_popup.animatedImage = img_popupraw
    }
}
```

Open to any alternative ways to show animating gif directly from a gif file. I am using Swift.

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use [SwiftGif](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif).

Import the `Gif.swift` in your project and do the following:

```
// Returns an animated UIImage
let jeremyGif = UIImage.gifWithName("jeremy")

// Use the UIImage in your UIImageView
let imageView = UIImageView(image: jeremyGif)
```

Comment: Or you may check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485308/how-to-show-gif-into-uiimageview-in-swift) out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i'm using `SDWebImage` for manage all image in app. Inclusive have `sd_animatedGIFNamed` func

install `pod 'SDWebImage'`

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Loader
//
//  Created by Pawan Kumar on 28/09/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Pawan Kumar. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FLAnimatedImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var animatedImageView: FLAnimatedImageView!
//  @IBOutlet weak var checkImageView: FLAnimatedImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url  = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Loader", ofType: "gif")
        print(url!)

        let data=NSData(contentsOfFile: url!)
        //print(data)
        let fff=FLAnimatedImage(gifData: data as Data?)
        let imageView=FLAnimatedImageView()
        imageView.animatedImage=fff
//
//        imageView.frame=CGRect(x: animatedImageView.frame.minX, y: animatedImageView.frame.minY, width: animatedImageView.frame.width, height: animatedImageView.frame.height)


         imageView.frame=CGRect(x: animatedImageView.frame.minX, y: animatedImageView.frame.minY, width: animatedImageView.frame.width, height: animatedImageView.frame.height)

        print(imageView.currentFrameIndex)
        imageView.clipsToBounds=true
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




}
```

Create a view controller as shown in the code above. 
Note:- while creating an imageview in story board, set the class of image view as FLanimatedImageView.

It will work.

Here **Loader.gif** is the GIF image.