# Tiled Background Image Moving Diagonally In View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've seen many solutions out here but they're not exactly what I'm looking for. What I'm attempting to do is have the view's background to move an image multiple times-- slowly and diagonally rather than horizontally or vertically.

From a web designing perspective, this can be achieved with a tiled bg.gif where the image gives the effect of an image moving without additional programming.

**Example:**

[image]

However, I'm not sure whether this is achievable within Swift programming. I'm sure alternative solutions are out there like having a single image (a smiley face) tiled to fill the view frame and have it move diagonally by incrementing it's x & y coordinates.

I'm new to iOS development and Swift yet I am learning a lot! Much help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

refer this two links. it will help to achieve what you want. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485308/how-to-show-gif-into-uiimageview-in-swift) and [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229145/unable-to-show-a-gif-file-in-a-uiimageview-in-swift)

Update as advised in comment : download [SwiftGif](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif) and Import the Gif.swift in your project and do the following:

```
// Returns an animated UIImage
let myGif = UIImage.gifWithName("imggif")

// Use the UIImage in your UIImageView
let imageView = UIImageView(image: myGif)
```

here `imggif` is your gif image which shown in question. put it in your project

hope this will help :)

Comment: Oikay. Updating my answer. :)

Comment: Awesome find! I'll try this in a few hours but I'm curious whether this or my other idea of incrementing x & y coordinates is more efficient? Probably a single gif... if so, I'll have to design my own gif with the image moving at a speed and direction desired with the right cropping so it looks seamless when tiled.